# When post contains "iframe" fails with error 403

Tags: php, post, ionic-framework, iframe, http-status-code-403

I'm finishing an app about recipes with Ionic, and I have to save some recipes as favorites so they can be seen without connection. The recipes come in json from a wordpress page, and some of them have youtube video embeded with iframe.

On mobile I save the recipe json with SQLite, but also I have to save them on a remote database, to do this I have tried using post, but when the server detect that the recipe have an iframe gives me error 403.

For test I made a simple form:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="https://www.ecocesta.com/app_data/favoritos.php" enctype="text/json">
    <input name="idUsuario"><br>
    <input name="idReceta"><br>
    <input name="contenido"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="add">
  </form>
</html>
```

And the PHP that recive data is

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$direccion_db="127.0.0.1";
$login="app_admin";
$password="9XCorOl5";
$db="app_data";


// Create connection
$conexion = new mysqli($direccion_db, $login, $password,$db);
if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
    echo "Error Base de datos";
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['idUsuario']) && is_numeric($_POST['idUsuario'])) {
    $idUser = (float) $_POST['idUsuario'];
} else {
    echo("Es necesaria una id de usuario");
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['idReceta']) && is_numeric($_POST['idReceta'])) {
    $idReceta = (float) $_POST['idReceta'];
} else {
    echo("Es necesaria una id de receta");
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['accion'])) {
    $accion = $_POST['accion'];

    switch ($accion) {
      case 'add':
        echo("Add<br>");
        if (isset($_POST['contenido']))  {
            $contenido = $_POST['contenido'];
        } else {
            echo("Es necesario un contenido");
            exit();
        }
          nuevoFavorito($idUser,$idReceta,$contenido,$conexion);
        break;
      case 'delete':
        echo("Borrar");
        borraFavorito($idUser,$idReceta,$conexion);
        break;
      case 'get':
        recuperaFavoritos($idUser,$conexion);
          break;
      default:
        echo("Es necesaria una acción");
        exit();
        break;
    }
} else {
    echo("Es necesaria una acción");
    exit();
}

function nuevoFavorito($idUser, $idReceta, $contenido ,$conexion)
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO  favoritos (idUser,id_receta,contenido) VALUES (".$idUser.",".$idReceta.",'".$contenido."')";
    echo($sql);

    if ($conexion->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {
      echo "New record created successfully";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conexion->error;
    }
}
?>
```

When I send this in "contenido" fails with 403:

```
<iframe class=\\\"video-youtube\\\" src=\\\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/6S9c5nnDd_s\\\" width=\\\"560\\\" height=\\\"315\\\" frameborder=\\\"0\\\" allowfullscreen=\\\"allowfullscreen\\\"></iframe>
```

Any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Post your code with which data you are passing to remote server so can get idea whats going wrong in your code.

Comment: Message edited with code. Thanks.